# (After Merge) Changes not Seen in Pull Request Seen in Commit

Tags: git, github

I have a local branch X, which is branched from my DEV branch. I've made some changes to file F1, added and committed only file F1 locally, then pushed to my remote for branch X. Then, I merged branch X to DEV. Note that in the pull request, I see that only file F1 is changed as expected.

However, after the pull request is merged and the change pulled, and see two commits, C1 and C2 -- C1 for my changes in branch X, and C2 for "Merge pull request". There is no diff between C1 and C2, but when I check C1 (meaning compare it with the previous commit), I see that F2 (another file I didn't change, which also didn't show up in my diff for pull request) is changed in that commit. Therefore, file F2 is modified as a result of me merging my pull request. How is this possible?

Some details:

```
commit 0945d3c91c1d28f779c4db5c86c24b0d44cdaddd
Merge: d2f43be 79e5699
Author: nickname<company email>
Date:   Mon Feb 25 22:49:07 2019 -0800

Merge pull request #SOME_NUMBER in REPO_NAME from X to DEV

* commit '79e56991a992c762266d75dd1e62e72012e0ebe6':
      my commit message.

commit 79e56991a992c762266d75dd1e62e72012e0ebe6
Author: Full official name <company email> <--also, why is a different name displayed here?
Date:   Mon Feb 25 22:43:41 2019 -0800

    my commit message


commit 15a85ccecf21530c09524c89dc65dca35d0faecb
Merge: ce5917b d2f43be
Author: Another person <email>
Date:   Mon Feb 25 19:37:09 2019 -0800

    Merge branch 'DEV' of repo_name into DEV
```

The "previous commit" before my change is 15a85-

Note:

I merged the pull request at 22:49.
I'm able to see changes to file F2 in the 22:43 commit -- the one with my official name.

Comment: Exactly how are you viewing these changes? Different Git commands do different things here: `git log -p` vs `git show`, for instance. It may help to include exact commands (cut-and-pasted) and at least some of their output (the actual lines in the diff can be snipped, leaving only the `@@...` headers).

Comment: The reason for the different user names is that you made your Git commit on an actual development machine by running `git commit`, and that made a commit using your configured `user.name` and `user.email`. You made the merge commit using the clicky "merge" button on GitHub (I assume), so GitHub's Git made that commit with whatever you told *that* to use for your name and email. The email setting is right but the name one is set to some nickname.

Comment: @torek I used "git log". The pasted lines are from the actual output, only with my name and whatnot redacted.

Comment: @torek oh I see, Thanks! I did merge using the "merge" button on the GUI.

Comment: The output in the question't show *any* files changed, though. (This is what one should expect from `git log` on a merge commit.) I'm wondering which two commits you actually compared, since there's no comparison visible at all here.

Comment: @torek I meant comparing 79e56991a992c762266d75dd1e62e72012e0ebe6 to the previous commit. The diff there shows that I've changed another file, but I didn't. To recap: I changed only one file, and confirmed so in the pull request GUI -- by checking "all changes in this pull request". However, after merging, I noticed that another unrelated file is changed as well.

Comment: But which commit is the previous commit? The `git log` output above does not show it. All I can tell is that it's probably not `d2f43be`, as that's the parent of `0945d3c` and hence probably not the parent of `79e5699`. (Note that `git log --decorate --oneline --graph` helps to view the actual graph structure and hence parentage.)

Comment: @torek I didn't include the previous commit since I thought that not relevant. Okay, I'll update my question to include the previous commit now.

Comment: One easy way to see what's in most commits—except for merges—is to use `git show`, which runs `git diff` of that commit against its parent. That's why I asked how you viewed changes: if it was with `git show`, that should do the right thing for `79e5699`. (For that matter, so should `git log -p`: both behave well with ordinary commits.) But if you manually ran `git diff`, you could be selecting some *other* commit, not the parent of `79e5699`...

Comment: OK, so, how did you compare commits `15a85cc` and `79e5699`? (The edited question still uses something that is not from `git log --graph`, although if it's from `git log` without `--graph` we can still be pretty sure that `15a85cc` is the parent of `79e5699`.)

Comment: @torek I compared the two commits using git diff commit1 commit2, which doesn't show the extra file being changed (the one I didn't touch, let's call it F2). The snippet provided in the question body is from the simple "git log", without --graph. But to me, the key here is: why is the file F2 changed by my pull request/merge, yet it didn't show up in the pull request diff ("all changes in this pull request") displayed on the GUI? The diff for the actual commit should always be the same as whatever is displayed for the pull request, right?

Comment: OK, now I'm really confused: *"I compared the two commits using git diff commit1 commit2, which **doesn't show the extra file being changed**"* (emphasis mine). So why do you think it *is* changed?

Comment: @torek ah sorry, I meant does, not doesn't... That's the only place where I see that the extra file is changed (git diff 15a 79e). The change to F2 is not in my pull request, but somehow changed due to my pull request. (After investigating, I found that the previous person who did a commit before mine changed that file, F2. But in my commit, I reverted that file back to what it was before his commit. How is this possible, given that there is no diff for this file in my pull request?)

Comment: I think this whole thing would be clearer if you just pointed everyone to the repository in question. Of course if it's private, that won't work at all. But at this point I'm too confused as to what happened when, to whom, etc., to make heads or tails of the question!